# How to filter a pd.io.formats.style.Styler pandas object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If my question isn't clear he's an example:

`df_late` is a df that already holds data

`color_rows` is a function that colors df_late rows based on certain conditions

(The details of the data and the function is not important for my question)

```
styler_late = df_late.style.apply(color_rows, axis=1)
```

Now how would I go about filter out data from `styler_late`

Ex:

```
styler_late.loc[styler_late['ID'] = 1]
```

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: `style` is for the most part a terminal operation. It is a _visual_ representation of a DataFrame, and therefore loses most of the features of the actual DataFrame. You could filter the DataFrame _then_ style if needed.

Comment: What is a terminal operation? And ahh okay, guess I'll do that instead. Was hoping I could filter out stuff directly from the `style` object.

Comment: By "terminal operation" I meant that the styler is no longer a "DataFrame" but rather a _visualization_ of a DataFrame. Similar to a picture, which means that no future DataFrame operations can be performed (for the most part).